# Node/JavaScript Datetime and MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, datetime

Calling MYSQL stored procedure that take in a 'datetime' parameter from Node/JS app isn't seem to be working correctly.

Calling MySQL procedure from within sql works ok, but not from JS. Here is my psuedo code:

```
 //procedure
 Proc(IN startDate datetime) {... select * from tbl where start = Date(datetime) ..}

 //this works ok from sql
 Call Proc (NOW())

 //From Node/JS, these don't seem to get the correct results
 connection.query(call proc(new Date())
 connection.query(call proc(getFormattedDate(new Date())
```

Edit: I am using this function to return formatted date.

```
var getFormattedDate = function(Date_toYMD) {
Date.prototype.toYMD = Date_toYMD;

    var year, month, day;
    year = String(Date_toYMD.getFullYear());
    month = String(Date_toYMD.getMonth() + 1);
    if (month.length == 1) {
        month = "0" + month;
    }
    day = String(Date_toYMD.getDate());
    if (day.length == 1) {
        day = "0" + day;
    }
    return year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Today's date works like this in JavaScript:

```
var dt = new Date;
console.log(dt.getFullYear()+'-'+(++dt.getMonth())+'-'+dt.getDate());
```

Comment: Thats what I have. My above code is pseudo, but I ma using this function which is same as yours var getFormattedDate = function(Date_toYMD) {
    Date.prototype.toYMD = Date_toYMD;
   
        var year, month, day;
        year = String(Date_toYMD.getFullYear());
        month = String(Date_toYMD.getMonth() + 1);
        if (month.length == 1) {
            month = "0" + month;
        }
        day = String(Date_toYMD.getDate());
        if (day.length == 1) {
            day = "0" + day;
        }
        return year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
};